# $G$-invariant subspaces in $K[G]$

Tags: representation-theory

Let $K$ be an algebraically closed field and $G$ an linear algebraic group (i.e. a group object of the category of affine varieties over $K$). Denote by $A$ the coordinate ring of $G$. Then the right multiplication makes $A$ a $G$-module: $(\rho(x)f)(y)=f(yx)$ ($f \in A, x,y \in G$).

I want to understand the proof of the following statement. (III§2 (2.4) of [this book](https://books.google.de/books?id=BoIOngEACAAJ).)

> For every finite-dimensional linear subspace $V$ of $A$, there exists a finite-dimensional $G$-invariant subspace $W$ of $A$ such that $V \subset W$.

Proof. It suffices to see that the case where $V=Kf$ for $f \in A$. Denote by $\mu$ the multiplication $G \times G \to G$, then $\mu^*f = \sum_{i=1}^n f_i \otimes g_i$ for some $f_i,g_i \in A$, under the identification $K[G\times G] = A \otimes_K\!A$. Then an easy calculation shows that $\rho(x)f = \sum g_i(x)f_i$. Thus the $G$-orbit of $f$ is contained in the linear subspace of $A$ generated by $f_1,\dots,f_n$.

**Question: Why $\sum_i Kf_i$ is $G$-invariant?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not. The argument works differently: The $G$-orbit of $f$ is contained in a finite-dimensional subspace of $A$ (namely, the one spanned by $f_1, f_2, ..., f_n$). Hence, the $K$-linear span of the $G$-orbit of $f$ is finite-dimensional. This span is the $W$ you are looking for (it is clearly $G$-invariant, being the span of a $G$-orbit).